# How can I see what the JVM is doing?

Tags: java, debugging, deployment, jvm

I run in a problem with the new update of `java 7u51`, I'm trying to set up the `Deployment rule set` to allow or not to run different application, base on its URL.

I have everything running, the deployment rule set file is signed and in the right place and even I'm available to match some URL to don't allow it to run.

But I don't know why some URL doesn't match.

So, I would like to debugger what `JVM` is doing and see if I can get why some URL are not matching.

Could somebody tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Does the JVM log help ?

Comment: I can't see the log or Java console when the java web start application is launched. Is `javaws` using a different log file or I have to do something else to available java console using `javaws`?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of any debugger you could use, however you can use the Java log (or Java console if in a browser).

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: I can't see the log or Java console when the java web start application is launched. Is `javaws` using a different log file or I have to do something else to available java console using `javaws`?